# Understanding 제일 좋아하는 유튜브 채널이 뭐예요?

Tags: grammar, particle

I have the following sentence (taken from a youtube video)

> 제일 좋아하는 유튜브 채널이 뭐예요?

Which translates as

> What is your favourite Youtube channel?

One thing that captured my attention in this sentence is the use of 좋아하는.

I know that given the adjective 좋다 (to be nice) we can construct the verb 좋아하다 (to like) but in this case seems to me that 좋아하는 = stem of 좋아하다 + 는 to construct another adjective?

I think this pattern is common to transform verbs into adjective and nouns, is this the use of it here?

Comment: it's asking which [thing] do you like most, it's not asking about the likeability of [thing]. How is this an adjective?

Comment: Is it an adverb then since is "most liked"?

Comment: "Which youtube channel do you like the most?" -> it is probably the same thing as whatever "like" is here

Comment: Which at this point seems an adverb to me. Unless you clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 제일 좋아하는 유튜브 채널이 뭐예요? = What is your favorite YouTube channel?

좋아하는 is an adjective, just like "favorite" is.

The sentence is fine, but I think it is even better to say it the other way.

> 어느 유튜브 채널을 제일 좋아하세요? = What YouTube channel do you like best?
> or 어떤 유튜브 채널을 제일 좋아하세요? = What kind of YouTube channels do you like best?

This sentence has the small advantage of going singular or plural simply by switching between 어느 and 어떤.